# LINQ Dynamic Assignment Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following code that I would rather have defined dynamically.

```
var candidates = People.Where(x=> (x.Age >18 && x.Age < 25)) .AsQueryable().Select(  c=> { c.Category = "F190 MISSING" ; return c; });
```

What I would however want is to have the above assignment defined as a string to be executed at runtime like so

```
String Conditional= "c=> {  c.Category = @0; return c; }";
String[]  ExpressionParameters = new [] {"F190 MISSING"};

var candidates = People.Where(x=> (x.Age >18 && x.Age < 25)).AsQueryable().Select( Conditional,ExpressionParameters);
```

So far, with my attempts, I have been getting either a **Expression expected** error message or a **NO PROPERTY C EXISTS IN PERSON**. How can I better define my assignment expression dynamically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone out there able to provide me with information that could help me better solve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one does not work, because c# compiler is not able to transform multi-line lambda into Expression Tree (and `IQueryable.Select` expects expression).

> The C# and Visual Basic compilers can generate expression trees only
>   from expression lambdas (or single-line lambdas). **It cannot parse
>   statement lambdas (or multi-line lambdas).** For more information about
>   lambda expressions in C#, see [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming
>   Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx); (...).

The second one can be done using libraries like DynamicLINQ.

Comment: The multi-Line I added to get it to display properly. So no need worrying about that. I am more out to learn how to define it dynamically. So far, my attempts at the second have not yielded much. I am currently using DynamicLINQ but yet able to get it correct is what.